# Exchange - Emails sent from mailbox automatically but can't track from where

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange

A user is complaining that they get daily bouncebacks for emails being sent to ex-employees.

These emails are being sent to mailboxes that have been deleted, so they can't be delivered. It's always a certain email received from a mailing list that encounters this (ie subject is always Mailing List xyz)

User has a mail rule set up to forward this email to five other users when received, but it does not include the obsolete emails that it is receiving bouncebacks for.

There are no corresponding mails in Sent Items. Using Mail Flow, we can see that the mailbox is trying to send these, and they are failing.

Somewhat stumped, does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: Hi, when you specify that the email is forwarded is it forwarding to a group, is the deleted user still a member of this group. Mail flow may not catch the email if the recipient address does not exist, another approach that I have just tested is the powershell cmdlet "Get-MessageTrace -SenderAddress <Email address of Recipient>" https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mail-flow/get-messagetrace?view=exchange-ps

Comment: Deleted user/s are not a member of any group in the rule, nor are they added individually to the rule..

Comment: The post is unclear : What is originating these messages? Where are they from and who were they sent to? Do they look like real bouncebacks or like spam? What are the message contents?

Comment: The bouncebacks are from us - they are stating that the address emailed is incorrect. So our server is rejecting them for a valid reason. The bouncebacks are sent to the original user mailbox which is the origin of the emails that fail to send. The message contents state that the email address is invalid, which is true.